# How to assign arbitrary values to frameaxis of a ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, style

Maybe the question is stupid or already has been asked, however, I cannot find an answer while searching Q&A.

Assume you have a

```
Table[x*y,{x,1,4},{y,1,4}]
```

Now applying `ListDensityPlot` will bring the values 1 to 4 to the frameaxis, which reflects somehow col and row of the table.

But how to assign arbitrary values **or even a string** to these frameaxis of a ListDensityPlot? Anybody can help?

[image: MWE]

Comment: You want to modify the [`FrameTicks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks.html) I think

Comment: @JasonB - I tried `Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{{-1, 1, 1}, None}, {{-1, 1, 1}, None}}` But it's not really working. Even worse with `FrameTicks -> {{"-a", "a"}, {"-b", "c"}}`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For random values,

```
ListDensityPlot[Table[x*y, {x, 1, 4}, {y, 1, 4}], FrameTicks ->
  {{Transpose[{Range[4], RandomReal[1, 4]}], Automatic},
   {Transpose[{Range[4], RandomReal[1, 4]}], Automatic}}]
```

[image]

For string labels,

```
ListDensityPlot[Table[x*y, {x, 1, 4}, {y, 1, 4}], FrameTicks ->
  {{{{1, "hello"}, {3, "world"}}, Automatic},
   {{{1.5, "a"}, {3.2, "b"}}, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good! I will study that!! Thank you!

Comment: I got it! one has to link the original value to the new one. Make sens!