# Scaling the axis

Tags: plotting, scaling

I want to scale the x-axis in the plot by a factor of $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, When I change the variable in the command:

```
Plot[f,{Sqrt[3]r/2,0,20}]
```

I am getting an error as "tag Times in $\frac{\sqrt{3}r}{2}$ is protected"

How to remove this problem?

Comment: You try to scale the iterator -  that doesn't work. Scale the function argument instead...

Comment: That changes the entire problem itself.

Comment: you could scale the x-axis with this: [How to assign arbitrary values to frameaxis of a ListDensityPlot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112348/how-to-assign-arbitrary-values-to-frameaxis-of-a-listdensityplot)

Comment: maybe `ParametricPlot[{Sqrt[3]r/2,f[r]},{r,0,20}]`

Comment: @george2079, I used the command suggested but I am not sure whether this corresponds to the problem or not. I will state the problem, $r$ is along horizontal direction, whereas I have calculated the function along a line inclined at $\frac{\pi}{6}$, I want to plot the function along that inclined line.

Comment: If you want `f[r]` vs "distance along the incline" it would be `2 r/Sqrt[3]` ( or I'd do `r/Cos[Pi/6]` )

Answer (score 4):

You could use `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) to introduce a scaled variable to plot over.

For example, assuming `f` implicity depends on `r`, you could introduce `rscaled`:

```
f := Sin[r] + r; (* Example function *)
Plot[f, {r, 0, 20 2/Sqrt[3]}] (* Original Plot *) 
Plot[f /. r -> rscaled 2/Sqrt[3], {rscaled, 0, 20 }] (*Scaled Plot*)
```

Alternatively, it's simpler if `r` is an explicit argument. For example,

```
g[r_] := Sin[r] + r;
Plot[g[rscaled 2/Sqrt[3]], {rscaled, 0, 20 }]
```